# Getting numpy to import in Python (Pycharm), Anaconda installed

Tags: python, numpy, import, pycharm, anaconda

I am very new to python and I am trying to write a code to derive a first-order ODE. Because of this, I need certain packages (ex. numpy) to do this and installed Anaconda.

When I tried to use the "import numpy" command in PyCharm, it did not work. I got ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'.

I am very new and need all the help I can get to get the programs linked.

Thank you!

Comment: *It did not work* is vague to the point of worthless. Please read [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example

Comment: There, it is fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set your project interpreter to the python, that came with your anaconda installation.

Your installation path may differ from mine.

For a new project:
[image: new project settings]

If you want to change the settings for an existing project:
[image: project settings for existing project]

Comment: Hi @Alex bGoode I have same problem.I have set the anaconda virtual environment but the packages are not showing under "project interpreter" window. Also i have checked that nor the Anaconda 3 folder has bin neither the  conda environment i created(from conda prompt) has it.Please help

Answer (score 8):

The best practice is to use a separate Conda environment for each of your projects, and then install what you need for your project in those.

First, open Settings, and go to Project Settings | Project Interpreter. Then use the gear icon on the top right, and choose to add a new local interpreter:

[image: Add a new local interpreter]

Then, choose 'Conda Environment' on the left-hand side, and make sure to choose the Python version you want (if you're not sure, 3.6 is a good choice).

[image: Create a new Conda environment]

Finally, use the green '+' icon on the interpreter page to install a new package, just look for 'Numpy' and install it from the dialog there:

[image: Install Numpy]

Comment: Why do you have to install packages don't they come with installed with Anaconda, it works in Sypder directly I wonder why do we install in pycharm

Comment: This is independent of it being Spyder or Pycharm.  Anaconda only comes with common packages. You might want to add others- this is the beauty of Python that it is modular and you can add additional packages as you go.