# Can't import manually installed library in Pycharm

Tags: python, aws-lambda, pycharm, virtualenv, psycopg2

I am writing a python script which will run in AWS as lambda function. Since it needs to connect to a Postgres database, library `psycopg2` is required. It seems the standard `psycopg2` does not work with AWS lambda. I downloaded it from [this git repo](https://github.com/jkehler/awslambda-psycopg2).

I am using virtualenv for all the dependencies, so I copied the psycopg2-3.6 folder from the downloaded package to `[myproject]/env/Lib/site-packages`. In my main script this library is imported

```
import psycopg2
```

However when I run it in PyCharm, I got error:

```
  File "C:\Users\dxx0111\WorkSpace\iq-iot-lambda\app.py", line 2, in <module>
    import psycopg2
  File "C:\Users\dxx0111\WorkSpace\iq-iot-lambda\env\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from psycopg2._psycopg import (                     # noqa
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2._psycopg'
```

Based on the error message, it looks like it was able to locate the directory of `psycopg2` under virtual environment package folder. It just couldn't find `psycopg2._psycopg`. What am I missing here?

Comment: Psycopg2 has dependencies which has to be installed. sudo apt-get install python3 python-dev python3-dev

Comment: Have you checked that your pycharm interpreter is connected to the right environment?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48610659/getting-numpy-to-import-in-python-pycharm-anaconda-installed

Comment: You miss `psycopg2\_psycopg.pyd`. You shouldn't *manually install* the module (I suspect you've just copied files) but run `pip install` or `python setup.py install` from the source directory.

Comment: @phd I am running pycharm on my windows laptop, if I do pip install psycopg2, it won't work in AWS linux EC2 instance. That's why I have to download the library from that link which was compiled on a Amazon Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, the `psycopg2` library downloaded from that link only works on Amazon Linux because that is where the package was compiled on. It doesn't work on my Windows machine. In order to make it work locally, I had to install with `pip install psycopg2` to my virtual env. When I deploy to AWS Lambda though, I make the zip with the downloaded library. So different `psycopg2` in different platform. Now it works in both places.